# addTargetのSelectorの戻り値を受け取るには

Tags: ios, swift

下記コードのように、addTargetで紐付けるSelectorが戻り値を返す関数だった場合、その戻り値を受け取るにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

```
myButton.addTarget(self, action: "clikedButton", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

func clickedButton() -> String {
    return "clicked"
}
```

Comment: セレクタで結びつけられるメソッドは、返り値を持たず、引数がないか、`sender`を引数に持つか、`sender`と`NSEvent` or `UIEvent`のふたつを引数に持つメソッドに限られます。返り値を持つメソッドには結びつけられません。

Comment: すでに Harawoさんのコメントに十分説明されていると思うのですが、返り値を持つメソッドにactionを結びつけてはいけません。ビルド時にチェックの入らない方法で無理に結びつけても(現在ご質問にあるコードでは正しく結びつけられていませんが)、(運が良ければ)単純に戻り値が無視されるか、(運が悪ければ)アプリがクラッシュするだけです。